# HTTP500 result from SOAP request in python

Tags: python, soap, bioinformatics

this question might be fairly specific for one service but I don't understand why I am getting a HTTP500 response from the SOAP service. I am seeing the service I want to access and I see which parameters are required. Still I am getting HTTP500. Is there something wrong with the service or my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Import WSDL package
from SOAPpy import WSDL

# Create service interface
wsdlUrl = 'http://bioinf.cs.ucl.ac.uk/psipred_api/wsdl'

# Download the WSDL file
server = WSDL.Proxy(wsdlUrl)

# Get the information about which services are provided by this host
print server.methods.keys()

# After selecting the service of interest let's find out which arguments are necessary
callInfo = server.methods['PsipredSubmit']
for para in callInfo.inparams:
   print para.name, para.type

# Now let's discover what we will get back
for para in callInfo.outparams:
   print para.name, para.type

sequence = "MLELLPTAVEGVSQAQITGRPEWIWLALGTALMGLGTLYFLVKGMGVSDPDAKKFYAITTLVPAIAFTMYLSMLLGYGLTMVPFGGEQNPIYWARYADWLFTTPLLLLDLALLVDADQGTILALVGADGIMIGTGLVGALTKVYSYRFVWWAISTAAMLYILYVLFFGFTSKAESMRPEVASTFKVLRNVTVVLWSAYPVVWLIGSEGAGIVPLNIETLLFMVLDVSAKVGFGLILLRSRAIFGEAEAPEPSAGDGAAATSD"
email = "psipred@cs.ucl.ac.uk"
subject = "test"

result = server.PsipredSubmit(sequence, email, subject, "True", "False", "False", "all")

print result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine and I just tried to access the server via `suds` and it works.

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client('http://bioinf.cs.ucl.ac.uk/psipred_api/wsdl')
print('PsipredSubmit' in client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods)
>>> True
```

Are you usually using a proxy?

Perhaps the server was temporarily down?

---

```
sequence = "MLELLPTAVEGVSQAQITGRPEWIWLALGTALMGLGTLYFLVKGMGVSDPDAKKFYAITTLVPAIAFTMYLSMLLGYGLTMVPFGGEQNPIYWARYADWLFTTPLLLLDLALLVDADQGTILALVGADGIMIGTGLVGALTKVYSYRFVWWAISTAAMLYILYVLFFGFTSKAESMRPEVASTFKVLRNVTVVLWSAYPVVWLIGSEGAGIVPLNIETLLFMVLDVSAKVGFGLILLRSRAIFGEAEAPEPSAGDGAAATSD"
email = "psipred@cs.ucl.ac.uk"
subject = "test"
client.service.PsipredSubmit(sequence, email, subject, "True", "False", "False", "all")
>>> (reply){
>>>    message = "job submission succesful"
>>>        job_id = "2e9f0864-826a-11e6-9da3-00163e110593"
>>>    state = 1
>>>      }
```

Submitting a job with `suds` works, perhaps you just caught the server at a bad time or there is something wrong with your `SOAP` library?

Comment: My code breaks with result = server.PsipredSubmit(sequence, email, subject, "True", "False", "False", "all"). I can get the methods too. However, using a method gives HTTP500

Comment: @doom4: Have a look at the updated answer, perhaps that helps.

Comment: thanks. your code works using suds. I have no idea why it doesn't work for me in SOAPpy. I will just use suds since I am not an expert in SOAP and have no preference.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a 500 result means the server encountered an unexpected error while processing your request.

This could be a temporary situation which will get resolved in a day or two: perhaps the server has a bad RAM chip, or its disk is full.

Or it could be completely intentional: perhaps one of the values you submitted was somehow incorrect, and the server is basically saying "You screwed up; go away."  (In this case one hopes that the server would respond with a more helpful diagnostic message, but it ain't always so.)

If you have an official connection with the hosting organization, or if they're nice people willing to help, you might be able to send them a message asking what went wrong.

Comment: I contacted the service providers but didn't get any answer so far. Using their REST api I can access there service but they suggest moving the SOAP since REST is legacy :(